# Git Overwrite Error on push for certain file: Why won't git push --force or git stash work?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to push a file change via git. I added and committed the file just as I would do for any other push.  However, when I push I get this error:

`remote: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
remote:         filename.html
remote: Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
remote: Aborting`

The thing is, I did commit the changes.  I tried to redo the edits and ran through the add/commit process a few times, and every time I push I get the same error. Any idea how to fix?

I've tried to force the push with `git push --force origin branch` and `git push origin branch --force`.  Still the same error.

I tried to stash the changes its referencing in the error with `git stash` and it says `No local changes to save`.

I tried `git reset --hard origin/master`.  Still the same error when trying to push that specific file.  I have no problems push other files, just this one.

I'd like to be able to push changes to this file, I'm just not sure how to get past this error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the complete text I get when I try to push:

`Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 418 bytes | 418.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: **** Pulling changes into Live [Hub's post-update hook]
remote:
remote: From /var/git/html
remote:  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
remote: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
remote:         filename.html
remote: Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
remote: Aborting
remote: Updating fb7c657..b64906e
To website.com:/var/git/html.git
   bf653d3..b64906e  master -> master`

Comment: Many things makes no sense here. One doesn't push *files* in git. You only push *commits*. And no merge can occur on a push. Remote refs are updated along the rules of fast-forward merging, yes, in a sense, but in **no** circumstances the process would merge anything locally on a push. Really hard to figure out what happened from your description.

Comment: In this case, I mean that when I push commits that feature changes for that specific file. It specifically references merges in the error message. Thanks for taking the time to comment @RomainValeri I'll add the entire text I get on push to the post. Let me know what you think

Comment: That's what I thought : a *pull*. Look at GitHub's remote log : there is a hook launching a pull. It doesn't change much to your problem, I admit that. But it makes *way* more sense now. I don't get why you can't simply add/commit your file, though. Yet >:-)

Comment: I've noticed that before but I didn't think much of it.  I'm not as experienced as I'd like to be with git.  I guess I will look into what is causing that hook and maybe I'll get some insight as to what is going on.  I've no idea why I can't at least force a push after its committed, it certainly has me stumped.  Thanks again @RomainValeri if you have any more insight or maybe some resources you could suggest it would be much appreciated

Comment: `--force` doesn't change anything here, you're forcing an open door. The remote *accepts* your push, even without force, then it executes the ref update, and at this point its hook mechanism kicks in, "hey! has something just been pushed? Execute this." ... cue the pull. This "error" is, in a strange way, confirmation that your push *worked*. If you didn't intend to put that hook into place and can disable it, I'd do that.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for clarifying.  I didn't put the hook in place myself as I didn't set up the git on this project.  It is possible, I guess, that I put it there unintentionally over the course of working on this site, though I don't think that this is the case.  I will have to dive in more on how to remove hooks and maybe try to find out why it is there in the first place. Good catch, I never would have thought to look into that myself @RomainValeri

Answer (score 2):

This is probably more appropriate as a comment but I lack the reputation to leave one.

What do you see when you run a `git status` ?

Are you certain you have the latest of your master branch?

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike.  I encounter this error only if I make changes to that specific file.  So if I run `git status` then it tells me `On branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.` Then it tells me filename.html is not staged for commit like normal.  So then I add and commit the file.  Then I go to push and it gives the error I mentioned above.

Comment: And yea, I do a git pull before I start editing to be sure I have everything up to date.  Appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: @Mike You sound like someone who deserves to comment more often.